# With JSDoc, how do I doc a param type to match a param used in a global method like fetch()?

Tags: fetch, jsdoc

I'm writing some fetch interceptors in JavaScript. I've got a few functions that take the [`init` object param](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#parameters) from fetch (2nd arg) and return a modified version of it. Via JSDoc I want to note both the `@param` and `@returns` types should match the structure of the `init` param. How do I do this? And/or is this advisable?

Since I only modify a subset of the many properties of `init` I've also considered creating my own *custom* object type with *just those properties referenced/modified*. That might make sense-- `init` can have whatever props, but my method needs/cares only about these specific ones. But then, when I'm writing or adjusting the function itself, I'd like to know if I am incorrectly referring to a property that does not actually exist on `init`. So I think it makes sense in a way to have a full typeDef of this. But I welcome advice against this.

What I've tried:
I've read that even with JavaScript, custom JavaScript types can be imported from typings files for various modules. I don't have experience with this. And in this case, fetch() is a [W3C browser standard?](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-method) so would there even be official typings for that somewhere on the interweb?

I've concocted something like this:

```js
/**
 * Customize the config (init) for a fetch with our
 * own specific props
 *
 * @param {{manually list all props here? or create my own typeDef? Oh no }} config
 * @returns {ditto} new Config
 */
function getCustomConfig(config) {
//do something
return newConfig;
}
```

What's the best way to approach this?

**EDIT UPDATE:**
As soon as I posted this I noticed that my IDE, VSCode recognizes a type called `RequestInit`. It comes from `typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts` and is defined as such:

```js
interface RequestInit {
    /** A BodyInit object or null to set request's body. */
    body?: BodyInit | null;
    /** A string indicating how the request will interact with the browser's cache to set request's cache. */
    cache?: RequestCache;
    /** A string indicating whether credentials will be sent with the request always, never, or only when sent to a same-origin URL. Sets request's credentials. */
    credentials?: RequestCredentials;
    /** A Headers object, an object literal, or an array of two-item arrays to set request's headers. */
    headers?: HeadersInit;
    /** A cryptographic hash of the resource to be fetched by request. Sets request's integrity. */
    integrity?: string;
    /** A boolean to set request's keepalive. */
    keepalive?: boolean;
    /** A string to set request's method. */
    method?: string;
    /** A string to indicate whether the request will use CORS, or will be restricted to same-origin URLs. Sets request's mode. */
    mode?: RequestMode;
    /** A string indicating whether request follows redirects, results in an error upon encountering a redirect, or returns the redirect (in an opaque fashion). Sets request's redirect. */
    redirect?: RequestRedirect;
    /** A string whose value is a same-origin URL, "about:client", or the empty string, to set request's referrer. */
    referrer?: string;
    /** A referrer policy to set request's referrerPolicy. */
    referrerPolicy?: ReferrerPolicy;
    /** An AbortSignal to set request's signal. */
    signal?: AbortSignal | null;
    /** Can only be null. Used to disassociate request from any Window. */
    window?: null;
}
```

Well then, this is what I want it seems. Apparently, VSCode has some magic to keep these types. But if I didn't have VSCode, where does this come from, is importing typescript itself enough to get this? And then, how would I know to look for `RequestInit` as the type I want, besides getting lucky here? Any advice on this is welcome as well as on the advisability of using this vs just referencing the few props I want.

Comment: This is late but anyway. On VSCode you can press the `Control` key (`Command` on mac) and click on any symbol and you go to the Typescript declaration file it's declared on. Try it on the `fetch` function and you go to the file `typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts` you've stumbled upon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a parameter type from a global function you can use `typeof theGlobalFunction` to get its type definition and extract the parameter with the utility type [`Parameters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utlity-types.html#parameterstype). For the `fetch` function it's going to be like the following:

```js
/**
 * Customize the config (init) for a fetch with our
 * own specific props
 *
 * @param {Exclude<Parameters<typeof fetch>[0], URL>} config
 * @returns {Exclude<Parameters<typeof fetch>[0], URL>} new Config
 */
 function getCustomConfig(config) {
    //do something
    return newConfig;
}
```

Of course, for the `fetch` function there is no advantage as it's easier to use the public-defined parameter type `RequestInfo` as you've already discovered. So, just do this instead:

```js
/**
 * Customize the config (init) for a fetch with our
 * own specific props
 *
 * @param {RequestInfo} config
 * @returns {RequestInfo} new Config
 */
 function getCustomConfig(config) {
    //do something
    return newConfig;
}
```